# What certificate usage flags are required for Firefox to offer the certificate as a client identifier?

Tags: firefox, ssl, client-certificates

I'm trying to use SSL client certificates with Firefox (34.0.5 on Mac is my test platform, but I want them to work on other Mozilla programs & systems).

I've set up a 2-level CA: top/root/self-signed certificate -> CA certificate

Then I create key/request/certificate/PKCS12 and install into Firefox.

When I navigate to a web server that requests client identification, Firefox asks me to pick a certificate, but it doesn't offer my new certificate.  Instead, my only choice is a user certificate I got from a different provider.

I think the problem is the Key Usage or Extended Key Usage settings in my client certificate -- I suspect that Firefox thinks my certificate isn't suitable for client authentication, so it doesn't offer it.

Does anybody know how Firefox picks suitable certificates for client identification purposes?

(The certificates import into the database OK and the parent certificates are trusted, so I think it's the user certificate flags.  However, it might be the one-level-up CA certificate not being authorized to sign client certificates?  Below are the Key Usages I'm trying [of course, I've tried a bunch of different combinations, but this is one set that doesn't work])

```
root@machine:/dir# openssl x509 -text -in tls/certs/TOP-LEVEL.crt 
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
[...]
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:2
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
[...]
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[...]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
root@machine:/dir# openssl x509 -text -in tls/certs/MID-LEVEL.crt
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
[...]
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[...]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
root@machine:/dir# openssl x509 -text -in user.crt
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[...]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 0):

My premise was (probably) incorrect.  It turns out that when an SSL server requests a client-side certificate, it sends a list of all the CAs that it will accept, and the client should send a certificate signed by one of those (if it has one).  I didn't have my new CA certificate in the right place, so it wasn't sent to Firefox as an acceptable CA, so Firefox didn't offer my new certificate as a choice of what to send.

I tracked it down with a combination of openssl s_client (which can be convinced to print a lot of useful information) and strace on openssl verify (you can see what certificate files it tries to open and where).

As usual, certificate problems require careful organization of files, paths and configurations.